# spring config server encrypt forbidden

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I've configured a [spring cloud config server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption) to use oAuth2 for security.  Everything is working well, except the encrypt end point.  When I try to access `/encrypt` I get a 403 Forbidden.  I am including the Authorization Bearer token in the header.  Is there a way to allow the encrypt end point to be called when the server is secured with oAuth, or is it always blocked?  Let me know if you would like to see any config files for this server.

Just for reference, here are the things that are working.

- calling `/encrypt/status` produces `{"status":"OK"}`
- The git repository is being pulled because I can access a property file from the server.
- oAuth authentication is working with Google because it takes me through the logon process.

  Here is the spring security settings.

```
    security: 
     require-ssl: true 
     auth2:  
       client:  
         clientId: PROVIDED BY GOOGLE  
         clientSecret: PROVIDED BY GOOGLE  
         accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token  
         userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth  
         scope:  
            - openid  
            - email  
            - profile  
      resource:  
         userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo  
         preferTokenInfo: true  
       
    server:  
       port: 8443  
       ssl:  
         key-store-type: PKCS12  
         key-store: /spring-config-server/host/tomcat-keystore.p12  
         key-alias: tomcat  
         key-store-password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
```

Here are my dependencies from the POM file so you can see the version of the libraries I'm using.

```
<parent>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>  
    <relativePath/>  
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->  
</parent>  
<properties>  
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>  
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>  
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>  
</properties>  
<dependencies>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>  
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>  
<dependencyManagement>  
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>  
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>  
            <type>pom</type>  
            <scope>import</scope>  
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>  
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add the Spring Security configuration?

Comment: Which version of Spring Cloud Config are you using?

Answer (score 15):

I solve it implementing this WebSecurityConfigurer. It disables CSRF and set basic authentication.In Spring Boot 2.0.0 you cannot disable CSRF using properties it forces you to implement a java security config bean.

```
package my.package.config.server;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .httpBasic();
;
    }


}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes this helps. So. Much. Fought with this issue for several days after upgrading our server to SB 2. Note that this is not referenced in the docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_security

Answer (score 2):

We must implement WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in configuration related class. So that the encrypt/decrypt services can be accessible. Make sure that you have configured **secret.key** in bootstrap.properties or application.properties.

Answer (score 2):

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Try the following instead of:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, I needed to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and in the configure method I disabled CSRF token.

```
          http
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")                
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/error**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```