# Using Spring Cloud Config not getting encrypted value?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am experimenting with Spring Cloud Config Server for encryption/decryption of config values.

For this, under Config Server project made following changes:

In **bootstrap.properties**

```
encrypt.key=abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh
```

I have also updated JCE using following command in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine:

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-unlimited-jce-policy
```

[image]

But after issuing a POST request, I couldn't see anything in response.

[image]

Ideally, encrypted text of the request body should be coming as response.

[image]

Sample project: https://github.com/Omkar-Shetkar/pluralsight-springcloud-m2-git

What could be missing here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually due CSRF, was getting 401-unauthorized response. Since Spring Boot 2.0, we can disable this in code.

Detailed answer is available here:
[spring config server encrypt forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281778/spring-config-server-encrypt-forbidden)

Following above steps solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting out there, If someone is stuck with my silly mistake,  even after doing all above things, if /encrypt endpoint is still not authorized.

Please check your security adaptor class. If you have overridden below method as well

```
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password(passwordEncoder().encode(userPassword))
        .roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin")
        .password(passwordEncoder().encode(adminPassword))
        .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
  }
```

You need to provide these credentials, under Basic Auth option of Authorization tab

[image]